# Why do my ember tests give me TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function?

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, qunit

here is the error from the `ember test --serv` output:

```
Integration | Component | date-time-input: it renders
    ✘ TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'elem.getAttribute( name )')
        http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:1685
```

This happens with all of my Integration and Acceptance tests.

How do I debug this error without a decent stack trace?
is there a way to configure ember to give me a decent stack trace?

Here is the test for the above error:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('date-time-input',
  'Integration | Component | date-time-input', {
    integration: true,
  });

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  // Set any properties with this.set('myProperty', 'value');
  // Handle any actions with this.on('myAction', function(val) { ... });
  let two = Ember.Object.extend({
    someDate: null,
  });
  this.set('two', two);
  this.render(hbs`{{date-time-input model=two field='someDate'}}`);

  assert.notEqual(this.$().text().indexOf('2016'), -1);
});
```

and the corresponding component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  fieldValue: Ember.computed('model', 'field', function () {
    let fieldName = this.get('field');
    let value = this.get('model.' + fieldName);
    return value;
  }).readOnly(),

  actions: {
    dateChanged: function (value) {
      let model = this.get('model');
      let field = this.get('field');

      model.set(field, value);
    },
  },
});

{{flat-pickr
  dateFormat='F j, Y at'
  timeFormat='h:i K'
  value=fieldValue
  enableTime=true
  onChange=(action 'dateChanged')
}}
```

here is my repo, in case anyone is curious: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/aeonvera-ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually getting a useful stacktrace, though in the compiled `vendor.js` rather than in the source files.

If you're using Chrome, open up `assets/vendor.js` in the sources panel. Then set a breakpoint on line 1685. Because ember-cli creates source maps on asset compilation, Chrome should immediately take you to the corresponding line in the source file.

It's annoying that Testem doesn't point to the the source file, but you should be able to work your way back from the compiled files all the same.

(Also, it looks like the top line of your stack trace is from jQuery, if that helps.)

Comment: so, through debugging, I found that the attribute it was trying to get was `data-tooltip` still don't know why the getAttribute method wasn't a function on `elem`, but.. I looked up the foundation docs again (css framework), and saw that I was configuring my tooltips incorrectly. So I removed the `data-tooltip` binding, and all my tests pass now.

Super weird.